# Unix PAM module fails on login/lock screen - Permission denied - exit code 13

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, pam, zenity

### How it works?

I'm back with yet another issue I can't figure out by myself. Basically what I have is 2 factor authentication (2FA) module based on Python PAM and with NFC card reader. Once user is prompted for password 2FA **Zenity** dialog pops up asking for PIN code, user enters it and auth is successful.

### When it breaks?

This solution works great while user is logged in, when saving files and being asked for password or using `sudo` in terminal. Once user is locked out (displayed lock screen) or has to login after restart, this solution fails to display **Zenity** dialogs.

### Code examples:

- Here is my PAM config file `/usr/share/pam-config/pprfid_pam.config` that contains:

```
    Name: 2FA PAMpy RFID Authorization
    Default: yes
    Priority: 192
    Auth-Type: Primary
    Auth:
        [success=end default=ignore]    pam_exec.so seteuid debug log=/var/log/pprfid.log /usr/local/bin/pprfid_pam.py
    Auth-Initial:
        [success=end default=ignore]    pam_exec.so seteuid debug log=/var/log/pprfid.log /usr/local/bin/pprfid_pam.py
```

- Here is my Python PAM module file `/usr/local/bin/pprfid_pam.py` that does the magic of 2 factor authentication.. and here is the part of **Zenity** command, that doesn't work:

```py
    # ...
    Popen("/usr/bin/zenity --forms --width=199 --height=100 --title '2FA' --text='Authorization' --add-password='PIN' --ok-label='Authorize' --cancel-label='Cancel' --separator=',' --display=:0.0", shell=True, stdout=PIPE )
    # ...
```

### Error!

As mentioned above, once I'm locked out or restarting machine and trying to login via lock/login screen I get this error in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
    Jul 24 18:13:14 ubuntu unix_chkpwd[46760]: password check failed for user (testuser)
    Jul 24 18:13:14 ubuntu kcheckpass[46747]: pam_unix(kde:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=testuser
    Jul 24 18:13:14 ubuntu kcheckpass[46761]: pam_exec(kde:auth): open of /var/log/pprfid.log failed: Permission denied
    Jul 24 18:13:14 ubuntu kcheckpass[46747]: pam_exec(kde:auth): /usr/local/bin/pprfid_pam.py failed: exit code 13
```

### My attempts to fix this:

1. Obviously first thing I did was checking permissions and setting them as follows:

```bsh
    root@ubuntu:~# chown -R root:root /usr/local/bin/pprfid_pam.py
    root@ubuntu:~# chown -R root:root /var/log/pprfid.log
    root@ubuntu:~# chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/pprfid_pam.py
    root@ubuntu:~# chmod 0755 /var/log/pprfid.log
```

2. I double checked that `DISPLAY` was set correctly, and it indeed was set to `:0.0`.

### Question!?

What am I doing wrong? I'm really new to PAM module development, but I have feeling that permissions are being denied due to fact I'm running GUI as root, but I'm not willing to shoot blindly.. so I'm reaching out to Unix gurus - please help!

*Thanks in advance,*
**@richardev**

### Update #1

Reading related articles and comments, and talking on some other forums it seems that the issue here is most likely due to **Zenity** or the PAM module itself not being able to run as GUI. To do that I'm supposed ti integrate it via display manager - in my case I have **SDDM**. I will try to test some scenarios in `/etc/pam.d/*` config files and see if I can force it to run.

### Update #2

`/usr/share/pam-config/pprfid_pam.config` covers all the auth points.. but **Zenity** won't display outside session (on login/lock screen), so I guess I really need to integrate this module into **SDDM** GUI directly :thinking:.

### Dead end / solution (kind of)

After some digging I decided to remove `/usr/share/pam-config/pprfid_pam.config` that covers `common-auth` and simply allow **PAM** module to run within user session after login. *I will have to figure out another way to trigger my python scripts on **SDDM** display manager.*

I'm not 100% sure if **PAM** supports cross-connecting with display managers (**SDDM** in my case) and I've read many posts, that say it's not possible - which is why I'm reducing my **PAM** modules coverage.